# cvCanny and float 32 bit (IPL_DEPTH_32F) problem

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, edge-detection, itk

I have some problems with [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)s **cvCanny(...)** and the Image data types it can handle. Well, maybe you guys/gals know a solution.

I have a 32 bit float image and I want to perform cvCanny on it.
The problem is cvCanny can only handle "IPL_DEPTH_8S" or U (signed / unsigned short), or at least that's what I suspect.  The OpenCV manual does not indicate how much it can handle and this line in cv/cvcanny.cpp didn't raise my hopes:

```
...
if( CV_MAT_TYPE( src->type ) != CV_8UC1 ||
CV_MAT_TYPE( dst->type ) != CV_8UC1 )
CV_ERROR( CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "" );
...
```

The images I have are greyscale / single channel float32 bit
and the values in the image are between 0.0 and 16.0. Casting my float32 to unsigned short wouldn't help much since the values would loose their precision and I would miss edges with OpenCVs canny.

Do you guys/gals happen to know a solution for my problem? (besides using [ITK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insight_Segmentation_and_Registration_Toolkit) :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, since `cvCanny` only supports single-channel 8-bit images, the only thing I can think of is to scale each value in your image by `255/16` into a new image of type `CV_8UC1` so that it ranges from `0 - 255` to minimize the precision you've lost.

Comment: OpenCV prides itself as software that sees ... how much can u see with 8bit depth ... i don't get it. Thanks for the scaling tip.

Comment: Well, the Canny edge detector was supposed to be used for grayscale images so 8-bit should be enough. In any case, if you want to request a feature on OpenCV you should go here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=22870&atid=376680 ...